# How to slove AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys' in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, dictionary, module

```
    if w in data:
        return data[w]
    # for getting close matches of word
    elif len(get_close_matches(w, data.keys())) > 0:            
        yn = input("Did you mean % s instead? Enter Y if yes, or N if no: " % get_close_matches(w, data.keys())[0])
        yn = yn.lower()
        if yn == "y":
            return data[get_close_matches(w, data.keys())[0]]
        elif yn == "n":
            return "The word doesn't exist. Please double check it."
        else:
            return "We didn't understand your entry."
    else:
        return "The word doesn't exist. Please double check it."
```

Answer (score 2):

`data` object in the code is not a dictionary. It's a list and lists don't have keys. You need to implement `data` object as a dictionary.

[Difference between List and Dictionary in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-list-and-dictionary-in-python/)